# Django-cms 3.5.2 ImportError: no module named djangocms_admin_style

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, django-cms

I have been manually installing Django-cms 3.5.2 error. I am following the install Django-cms by hand instructions. I do fine until it asks me to run the migrate command. At that point I get an ImportError: No module named djangocms_admin_style. I am running the app in a virtualenv and can see the module in my env. Anyone have an idea of what's going on? Below is the full traceback.

$ python manage.py migrate

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "manage.py", line 22, in  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/**init**.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
module = import_module(entry)

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/**init**.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File "", line 2254, in _gcd_import

File "", line 2237, in _find_and_load

File "", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ImportError: No module named 'djangocms_admin_style'